# Which President has had the greatest number of their actions ruled unconstitutional?

Tags: united-states, president, constitution, democracy, supreme-court

Abraham Lincoln suspended habeas corpus and the court ruled that it wasn’t within his authority, I am wondering which President did the most things that the Supreme Court **explicitly** ruled were unconstitutional, not actions where their constitutionality is questioned by the public but hasn’t be directly ruled against.

Comment: Does overturning a law they signed count?

Comment: Yes, I think signing a unconstitutional law would qualify, maybe less so though.

Comment: But wouldn't there, or at least shouldn't there be, a difference between actions of the President alone (e.g. executive orders) and where he is "simply" signing a law passed by both houses of Congress? I do understand the concept of "the buck stops here", I just want to ensure we understand the OPs intent.

Comment: I'd think we should leave laws out of it, unless something about the signing _itself_ was deemed unconstitutional (such as the line-item veto).  Otherwise, that opens it up to every law that has ever been rejected by SCOTUS on constitutional grounds that wasn't passed by veto-override. (So basically all of them)

Comment: Ok, let's do that.

Answer (score 7):

FDR, in part, because he was in office the longest, and in part, because the courts early in his Presidency took a crabbed view of what kinds of economic regulation were constitutional that courts later in his Presidency abandoned.

A list of the number of executive orders made by President can be found in this [Congressional Research Service report](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/95-772.pdf). FDR at 3522 executive orders and an average of 285.64 executive orders per year, is the clear leader by either measure. A general legal overview of this area of law that does not quantify the number held unconstitutional in each administration can be found [here](https://www.fjc.gov/history/administration/judicial-review-executive-orders). Very granular detail without summaries is available [here](https://www.phe.gov/s3/law/Pages/ExecOrders.aspx).

Statutes have been declared unconstitutional by the U.S. Supreme Court [a bit fewer than 500 times](https://constitution.congress.gov/resources/unconstitutional-laws/) since 1789 when the current constitution took effect (but any court state or federal can declare a law to be unconstitutional, this power is not reserved to the U.S. Supreme Court in the United States).

Comment: This is probably correct, but have you actually done the counting?

Comment: I would think also that it makes sense to consider presidential terms individually, rather than tenure as a whole (or if we do look at tenure as a whole to consider it in terms of judgments per year).

Comment: @JamesK I've seen the answer in charts in the past (in hard copy) although I haven't sourced it with an online source.

Comment: Ironically, I don’t think the large-scale internment of Japanese-Americans was ruled unconstitutional, even though it’s one of the things most likely to be thought of in this category.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm If I recall correctly, the [original presidential directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_9066#Transcript_of_Executive_Order_9066) relating to *large-scale internment of Japanese-Americans* didn't require internment from everywhere, only removal from Defense-related assets.  What happened is the general in charge on the West Coast was racist and paranoid and... internment followed.  So it wouldn't *necessarily* have been a fit for this question.  FWIW Canada did pretty much the exact same thing to its Japanese-origin citizens.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You are correct. The case was *Korematsu v. U.S.* https://www.oyez.org/cases/1940-1955/323us214

Comment: What do you mean by "crabbed"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Narrow, restrictive, not open to new directions.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Technically, the Supreme Court did eventually hold it to have been unconstitutional, in a passing remark in *Trump v. Hawaii* (2018).

Comment: @NateEldredge it is worthwhile to quote the court's opinion here, attributed to Chief Justice Roberts: "The dissent’s reference to _Korematsu,_ however, affords this Court the opportunity to make express what is already obvious: _Korematsu_ was gravely wrong the day it was decided, has been overruled in the court of history, and—to be clear—“has no place in law under the Constitution.” 323 U. S., at 248 (Jackson, J., dissenting)."